# How to make Custom Validator to *check each attribute* of an object in *props* in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a props object named `car`, I want to validate each attribute of `car`. 
For example, the Rules are:

1. `color` must be only `white` or `black`
2. `name` Must be only `String`
3. `numberOfSits` between 4 and 2
4. `status` must be `Available` or `not Available`

I know that I need a Validator function in `car` something like `validator (val) =>{}` but **I don't know how should I implement it .**

I also know how to check a `String type` prop, For example, if I have a `Status` variable, `validator` be like :

```js
props:{
  Status:{
    type: String,
    default: 'Available',
    validator: function (value : string) {
      return ['Available', 'Not Available'].includes(value);
    }
}
```

Here is the Code for my Question:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CarComponent',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  props:{
    Car: {
       type: Object,
       required: true,
       default: () => ({ id: '',name:'',color:'',
         tireSize:'',numberOfSits:'', status: '', engineType: '' 
       }),
       //Validator must be here
     }
  }
});
```

I searched a lot about it but Didn't find what I want And Also I **don't** want to use any Library

Comment: *I don't know what should I write inside of it* - This is the key problem. We don't know either. What about **Car** needs to be validated? What are the rules for **Car**?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what do you mean "rules"? it's just an example , I just want to put those 4 items that I said in the Validator , you can think of a fruit with `name` , `color` and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is so obvious that I seriously wonder why you can't see it - the answer simply follows from the question:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CarComponent',
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    Car: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    default: () => ({ 
      id: '',
      name: '',
      color: 'white',
      tireSize: '',
      numberOfSits: 2, 
      status: 'Available', 
      engineType: '' 
    }),
    validator: (value) => {
      return typeof value.name === 'string' &&
        ['white', 'black'].includes(value.color) &&
        ['Available', 'not Available'].includes(value.status) &&
        value.numberOfSits >= 2 && value.numberOfSits <= 4
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked , thank you sir .It looks so easy and  I literally don't know why I didn't figure it out myself.